# Scipy Minimize - Unable to minimize objective function

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimize

I am trying to optimise a function to find max value of `rev_tot` using scipy minimise. Here `obj_data` is a list of probabilities, `prem` is a constant and `inc` can take any real value. Following is the code I have written for the objective function :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def objective(x,*args):

    prem = args[0]
    prob = args[1]
    inc = x[0]


    rev_tot = 0
    rev = 0
    del_p = 0.2*(1-np.exp(-2*(1-np.exp(-inc/400))))
    for i in range(len(prob)):
        rev = (prob[i]*(1+del_p)*prem) - inc
        rev_tot = rev_tot + rev
    return 1/rev_tot


prem = 3300
par = [0.9,0.1,0.5,0.4]
x0 = np.array([3]) # initial guess
solve = minimize(objective,x0,args=(prem,par),method='SLSQP')
solve.x
```

I want to find the `inc` value which will minimize `1/rev_tot`(and thus maximising `rev_tot`. 
When I call:

```
minimize(objective,x0,args=(prem,par),method='SLSQP')
```

the function runs, but `solve.x` shows no change in initial value. I am unable to figure out why the minimisation is not happening.

Comment: This is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the indentation is obviously not as intended. Please edit your question.

Comment: Mr. T gave a link to a description of a minimal, complete and verifiable example.  You have shown us your objective function, but your example is not complete and verifiable.  It would be much easier for someone to help you if the code could be copied and run without editing to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser : I have made the necessary changes to make the error reproducible. Apologies.

Comment: From the [documentation of `minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html):
  "The objective function to be minimized. `fun(x, *args) -> float` where x is an 1-D array with shape (n,) and args is a tuple of the fixed parameters needed to completely specify the function." The parameters of `objective` do not conform to this format.

Comment: Thanks, Shreyas, but it is not quite there yet.  If the code is run now, `minimize` raises the exception `TypeError: objective() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'inc' and 'prem'`.  I suspect you are missing `args=(inc, prem)`.  Also, the second argument of `minimize` is `x0`, the initial guess to be used by the minimize code.  You passed `inc`, which is almost certainly not correct--maybe you thought that would work instead of using `args`.  Take another look at the [`minimize` docstring](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) for more info.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser : I made the changes after going through the scipy minimize documentation. Now, even though I am not getting an error, but the minimisation is not happening. Can you please let me know why it's not working now ?

Comment: your code works for me

Comment: @Moritz : Are you able to find the optimal value of x[0] after minimizing the objective function ?

Comment: If that function isn't convex (and I suspect it isn't), then the whole idea of minimization makes no sense anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that the solver has to deal with tiny numbers due to your `return 1/rev_tot`. Hence changes over the x-axis are not well reflected in changes in y-values and the solver estimates that it has already converged:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def objective(x,*args):

    prem = args[0]
    prob = args[1]
    inc = x[0]

    rev_tot = 0
    rev = 0
    del_p = 0.2*(1-np.exp(-2*(1-np.exp(-inc/400))))
    for i in range(len(prob)):
        rev = (prob[i]*(1+del_p)*prem) - inc
        rev_tot = rev_tot + rev
    return 1/rev_tot

prem = 3300
par = [0.9,0.1,0.5,0.4]
x0 = np.array([2]) # initial guess
solve = minimize(objective,x0,args=(prem,par),method='SLSQP')
x_min = solve.x
print(x_min)
#plot your function to visualize the outcome
x_func = np.linspace(1, 100, 1000)
y_func = []
for item in x_func:
    y_func.append((objective(np.asarray([item]), prem, par)))

y_min = objective(np.asarray([x_min]), prem, par)

plt.plot(x_func, y_func)
plt.plot(x_min, y_min, "ro")
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
[2.]
```

[image]

Solution 1)
[Different solvers manage certain problems better than others.](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/mathematical_optimization/#a-review-of-the-different-optimizers) Change your solver to "Nelder-Mead". Output:

```
[63.07910156]
```

[image]

Solution 2)
Scale up your return value with `return 1000000/rev_tot` for solver "SLSQP". Output:

```
[63.07110511]
```

[image]